# What kind of security does `identity` provider in Kubernetes EncryptionConfiguration provide?

Tags: security, encryption, kubernetes, storage, etcd

Ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/encrypt-data/#providers

According to the docs

> Resources written as-is without encryption. When set as the first provider, the resource will be decrypted as new values are written.

`When set as the first provider, the resource will be decrypted as new values are written.` sounds confusing. If resources are written as is with no encryption into etcd, why does `decrypted as new values are written` mean ?

And following that

> By default, the identity provider is used to protect secrets in etcd, which provides no encryption.

What kind of security does `identity` provider give if no encryption happens and if encryption happens, what kind of encryption is it?

Comment: To clarify, you are asking how `identity EncryptionConfiguration` works or how its different form other providers?

Comment: I guess what I am trying to ask is, what does `identity` provider exactly help with, as in why's it there if it offers no encryption but the docs seem to talk about `decryption` and how it `protects secrets in etcd`. What kind of protection is this and how does decryption fit in here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in `etcd` about [security](https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/blob/master/Documentation/op-guide/security.md#does-etcd-encrypt-data-stored-on-disk-drives)

> Does etcd encrypt data stored on disk drives?

No. etcd doesn't encrypt key/value data stored on disk drives. If a user need to encrypt data stored on etcd, there are some options:

- Let client applications encrypt and decrypt the data
- Use a feature of underlying storage systems for encrypting stored data like dm-crypt

### First part of the question:

> By default, the `identity provider` is used to protect secrets in etcd, which provides no encryption.
> It means that by default k8s api is using `identity provider` while storing secrets in `etcd` and it **doesn't provide any encryption.**

Using [EncryptionConfiguration](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/encrypt-data/) with the only one provider: `identity` gives you the same result as not using `EncryptionConfiguration` at all (assuming you didn't have any encrypted secrets before at all).
All secret data will be stored in plain text in `etcd`.

Example:

```
    providers:
    - identity: {}
```

### Second part of your question:

> Resources written as-is without encryption.
> This is described and explained in the first part of the question

When set as the first provider, the resource will be decrypted as new values are written.

Take a look at this example:

```
    providers:
    - aescbc:
        keys:
        - name: key1
          secret: <BASE 64 ENCODED SECRET>
    - identity: {}
```

What this configuration means for you:

- The new provider introduced into your `EncryptionConfiguration` does not affect existing data.
- All existing `secrets` in `etcd` (before this configuration has been applied) are still in plain text.
- Starting with this configuration all new `secrets` will be saved using `aescbc` encryption. All new `secrets` in `etcd` will have prefix `k8s:enc:aescbc:v1:key1`.
- In this scenario you will have in `etcd` a mixture of encrypted and not encrypted data.

So the question is why we are using those two providers?

- provider: `aescbc` is used to write new `secrets` as encrypted data during write operation and to decrypt existing `secrets` during read operation.
- provider: `identity` is still necessary to read all not encrypted secrets.

Now we are switching our providers in `EncryptionConfiguration`:

```
    providers:
    - identity: {}
    - aescbc:
        keys:
        - name: key1
          secret: <BASE 64 ENCODED SECRET>
```

- In this scenario you will have in `etcd` a mixture of encrypted and not encrypted data.
- Starting with this configuration all new `secrets` will be saved in plain text
- For all existing secrets in etcd with prefix k8s:enc:aescbc:v1:key1 provider: aescbc configuration will be used to decrypt existing secrets stored in etcd.

> When set as the first provider, the resource will be decrypted as new values are written

In order to switch from `mixture of encrypted and not encrypted data` into scenario that we have only "not encrypted" data, you should perform read/write operation for all secrets:

`$ kubectl get secrets --all-namespaces -o json | kubectl replace -f -`

> why's it there if it offers no encryption but the docs seem to talk about decryption and how it protects.

It's necessary to have the provider type of `identity` if you have a mixture of encrypted and not encrypted data
or if you want to decrypt all existing `secrets` (stored in etcd) encrypted by another provider.

The following command reads all secrets and then updates them to apply server side encryption. More details can be found in [this paragraph](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kms-provider/#ensuring-all-secrets-are-encrypted)

`$ kubectl get secrets --all-namespaces -o json | kubectl replace -f -`

Depending on your `EncryptionConfiguration`, all `secrets` will be saved as not encrypted -if the first provider is: `identity` or encrypted if the first provider is different type.

**In addtion**

`EncryptionConfig` is disabled as default setting. To use it, you have to add `--encryption-provider-config` in your `kube-apiserver` configuration. `Identity` is not encrypting any data, as per [Encrypted Providers documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/encrypt-data/#providers) it has 3x `N/A`.